# Bootstrap navbar toggle not working, even with javascript included

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem that my navbar toggle is not working, any idea what I do wrong? I did include the JavaScript and used the code from the Bootstrap example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>NavBarTest</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Include also jQuery

Comment: Yes as the faceless man said you must include a jquery library - it must also be declared before your bootstrap js is included https://jsfiddle.net/qk76jahh/

Comment: I tried <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> is this the right include, it doesn't work either.

Comment: try the one i used in the the fiddle link

Comment: Thank you so much, It works find now. Unfortunately, I could not find this on the Bootstrap website itself.

Comment: On Bootstrap's website, on the Getting Started>Basic template, you can clearly see in the code sample: jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)